# Matrix transpose is not iterating

Tags: python, transpose

I'm trying to transpose a dataset of order about 60*75. I'm having a trouble iterating through the matrix to transpose it into 75*60 order. Each column would have different kind of data (numbers, words, mixture, URLs etc). I tried the following code. But it'd just give me the first column transposed.

```
f= open('input.txt', "rb")    
fw=open("output.txt", "wb")
l=f.read()
for row in l:
    print ''.join(row)
p= [[row[i] for row in l] for i in range(75)]
print p
```

Alternaticely I tried

```
a = np.array(l)[np.newaxis]
print a.T
```

None of them gave me the complete transposed matrix.

I even tried zip(*l) and map(zip(*l)).

I appreciate your help. 
Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

`f.read()` is a giant string containing all the file's contents. It is not some sort of structured data format; in particular, `for row in l` iterates over raw characters rather than rows of useful data.

If you want something more useful, the `csv` module might help, or perhaps something like `numpy.loadtxt`, depending on the format the file actually contains.

Comment: Thanks for replying. That makes sense. You mean should there be something like this after f.read()? ll= [x.split(',') for x in l.split('\n')] and then say for row in ll? That actually didn't work either.

Comment: @user3614557: Something like that might work. It depends heavily on the data format.

Comment: Problem still persists with iterating. It just gives me the header and not the rest of the data. In the sense, its transposing just the first column into first row and ignoring the rest.

Comment: @user3614557: Well, you're doing something wrong. I don't know what your code or data look like, so I don't know what that something is.

Comment: You're right. My data had a gap after every row that stopped it from iterating. Thanks for the help though.